# access to indexes of 2D array jquery element from inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a 2D array of **JQuery** elements (Grid) and I want to access to the index `i` and `j` of The element `Grid[i][j]` from inside the callback function of addEventListerner()

How can I do this?

```
grid[i][j].addEventListener('click',function(){\*here i want to access to the index i and index j*\});
```

Comment: Use `this` reference?

Comment: how can i access to the indexes using this?

Comment: i mean what should i write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a wrapper like:

```
rid[i][j].addEventListener('click', (function (i, j) {
  return function() {
    console.log(i, j)
  }
})(i, j));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `i` nor `j` inside the scope because `grid[i][j]` is an object, **it does not depend** on `i` nor `j`.

If you want to add event listeners on all elements of the object you should use a method to loop through it instead

Here I'm using two [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops:

```js
const grid = [['one', 'two', 'three'],['one', 'two', 'three'],['one', 'two', 'three']]

grid.forEach((e,i) => e.forEach((o,j) => {
  console.log(i,j);
}));
```